# How do I remove Library and Music from searching with Ripgrep and FZF?

Tags: macos, fzf, ripgrep

I'm trying to configure rg and fzf on my mac, but really cannot work out how to clear out lots of annoying files from search.

I have a ~/.gitignore with the following:

```
Library/*
Music/*
```

(and I also tried without the '*' at the end of the line)

and my zshrc looks like this:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='rg --files --hidden'
```

I've also tried putting globs in ~/.ignore and ~/.config/git/ignore. In every case, I always end up with loads of Library/ and Music/ matches.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you.

**EDIT**

With some further Googling I've discovered that it's actually not FZF that isn't working - it's that I'm using Ctrl+T to open fzf. If I type `fzf` it works as expected.

So the question now is how I can get Ctrl+T to have the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the [source code](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L43), my hackish answer to this is to add:

```
export FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND=$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND
```

to my .zshrc *after* oh my zsh is sourced.

Hope this helps!